# Email Notification needs to be sent to internal team after every form submission

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, cloudpagesurl

I have a landing page built in cloud page in SMFC with the smart capture form. The form is submitting the data to a DE table just fine.

Currently right now I am exporting this data manually to sftp and sending it to the Sales team on a daily basis.

I am wondering if there is a way to automate this where if a new contact is added to a DE and somehow fire a trigger email send to the Sales showing the details of the submission by email with some look up ampscript.

It is something I saw Woo Foo form do and was wondering if that is possible in SFMC.

Thanks

Comment: You can send a triggeredsend with ampscript upon submission:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createTriggeredSend.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you've got Journey Builder available, you could trigger a Journey at the time of form submission that will then send the submitted data via email to your sales people.

In order to do that, you'd have to build the Journey, set up an API package (so you can request a token and interact with SFMC's Journey Builder REST API) and change your landing page accordingly.

See here for details:

- offical docs: [Get Started with the Journey Builder API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/get-started-jb.htm)
- seemingly useful how to article: [Step by Step Guide to Trigger emails and Journeys via Rest API in Salesforce Marketing Cloud (SFMC) with Postman](https://alessiamastroianni.medium.com/step-by-step-guide-to-trigger-emails-and-journeys-via-rest-api-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud-a3dba0215d68)

EDIT 30.03.21:

I'm assuming this is the process you'd like to implement:

1. form gets filled by anon
2. form gets submitted
3. form data gets packed into an email
4. email gets sent to 1 or more sales team members

-- is that correct?

If yes, then the implementation would look like this:

1. set up the website with the form (does not necessarily have to be an SFMC CloudPage, but can be ofc)
2. set up a Data Extension to store the submitted form data (this DE should have at least 3 columns: SubscriberKey (hard coded to sales team group inbox), EmailAddress (hard coded to sales team group inbox) & FormData)
3. set up a Journey Builder API Entry Event based on that Data Extension,
4. send the required data into that event's endpoint when the form gets submitted.

This should lead to the desired outcome = the sales team receiving an email with the form data in it.

Comment: Hi @Tom, thank you for your comment and the links you have provided, but I am not understanding one thing here, As soon as the customer submits the form my sales team need to get the notification email, so in that case the above links show the insertion of data into the created DE but I wanted to use the DE with my sales team data and use that for sending... can you please be more precise on how I can do that ... Once again thank you so much for your comment.

Comment: Hi, my comment would have been too long, so I edited my original answer.